# In Akka, what happens if I watch() a dead ActorRef?

Tags: akka, watch

If I call context.watch() on an ActorRef that is already dead, am I guaranteed to still receive a termination message?

Also, after having received a termination message regarding a specific actor, do I still need to call unwatch()?

Also, are watch() calls reference counted? If I call watch() twice, followed by unwatch() once, am I guaranteed to still get termination messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the documentation is pretty clear:

> "One important property is that the message will be delivered
>   irrespective of the order in which the monitoring request and target’s
>   termination occur, i.e. you still get the message even if at the time
>   of registration the target is already dead."

- http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/general/supervision.html

And, you do not need to unwatch since the actor can't die twice, and it's not reference counted. It's binary.

Cheers,
√